# mysql data did not appear according to the id in html table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql table in the same database. First table is 'coi_system' and second, 'monthly_saving' which the id is refer from the first table. I want to display these two table data into [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew27F.png).

So, the 'monthly_saving' should be displayed in that Cost Saving Monthly html column refering to the id of the 'coi_system' but it turns out it display all the data of 'Jan 17' column into each of the result that makes each result display double [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiUIh.png). Heres the code,

```html
<?php

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM coi_system, monthly_saving where monthly_saving.id=coi_system.id"); 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $accountcode=$row['accountcode'];
    $department=$row['department'];
    $person_in_charge=$row['person_in_charge'];
    $project_title=$row['project_title'];
    $objective=$row['objective'];
    $how_to_do=$row['how_to_do'];
    $activities=$row['activities'];
    $project_started=$row['project_started'];
    $project_completed=$row['project_completed'];
    $target_cost_saving=$row['target_cost_saving'];
    $costsaving_afterjustification=$row['costsaving_afterjustification'];
    $costsaving_monthly=$row['costsaving_monthly'];
    $sum_of_month=$row['sum_of_month'];
    $targetsaving_currentmonth=$row['targetsaving_currentmonth'];
    $avg_monthly_saving=$row['avg_monthly_saving'];
    $todays_date=$row['todays_date'];
    $current_month=$row['current_month'];
    $Jan=$row['Jan'];
    $Feb=$row['Feb'];
    $Mac=$row['Mac'];
    $Apr=$row['Apr'];
    $May=$row['May'];
    $Jun=$row['Jun'];
    $Jul=$row['Jul'];
    $Aug=$row['Aug'];
    $Sep=$row['Sep'];
    $Oct=$row['Oct'];
    $Nov=$row['Nov'];
    $Dis=$row['Dis'];
    $id=$row['id'];
  ?>

  <div class="scroll">
  

  <tr id="row1">
      <td> </td>
      <td id="accountcode_row1"><div> <?php echo $accountcode;?></div></td>
      <td id="department_row1"><div> <?php echo $department;?></div></td>
      <td id="pic_row1"><div> <?php echo $person_in_charge;?></div></td>
      <td id="protitle_row1"><div> <?php echo $project_title;?></div></td>
      <td id="objective_row1"><div> <?php echo $objective;?></div></td>
      <td id="howtodo_row1"><div><?php echo $how_to_do;?></div></td>
      <td id="activities_row1"><div> <?php echo $activities;?></div></td>
      <td id="prostart_row1"><div> <?php echo $project_started;?></div></td>
      <td id="procompl_row1"><div> <?php echo $project_completed;?></div></td>
      <td id="targetcost_row1"><div> <?php echo $target_cost_saving;?></div></td>
      <td id="costafter_row1"><div> <?php echo $costsaving_afterjustification;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Jan;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Feb;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Mac;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Apr;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $May;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Jun;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Jul;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Aug;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Sep;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Oct;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Nov;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $Dis;?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $sum_of_month; ?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $avg_monthly_saving; ?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $todays_date; ?></div></td>
      <td><div><?php echo $current_month; ?></div></td>
      <td><div></div></td>
      <td><div> <?php echo $targetsaving_currentmonth;?></div></td>
```

I'm not sure where is the mistake but I have tried write it like this, `$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM coi_system, monthly_saving where id");` but thats not the solution. I truly need someones help in this as I'm not good with mysqli. Thankyou in advance!

UPDATE

This is table [monthly_saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv3nX.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC183.png) from 'coi_system' where the id is referred. Solved, but new problem, currently theres only 2 rows of results that appear which that has the 'monthly_saving' data. The rest didnt appear because they dont have any 'monthly_saving' data. So how to display them all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your table structure too.

Comment: Have you tried SQL JOIN?

Comment: *sidenote:* you know you can use `$row` variables directly without assigning them again, and `id`'s should be unique..right?

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi not yet because I thought I can write this simple as I'm still new in this and easy to understand. Should I try SQL JOIN?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone use `$row` variables directly without assigning them again how did you mean? Example? The id for the first table is set as primary key and the second table is set as index as I want it to refer from the first table. So I must make all the id unique?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * from coi_system, monthly_saving where monthly_saving.id=coi_system.id;
```

Comment: It works! But new problem, only two rows of results comes out.It only show the rows that has the 'monthly_saving' data. How to make all the data appear even if the row in 'monthly_saving' is null?

Comment: Why you want null also then your query will output irrelevant data again.

Comment: I mean, if theres no data in any column from 'monthly_saving' for that id, then all the other data didnt appear. Currently theres only 2 rows of results that appear which that has the 'monthly_saving' data. The rest didnt appear because they dont have any 'monthly_saving' data. So how to display them all?

Comment: try to append or monthly_saving.id=null;

Comment: `"SELECT * from coi_system, monthly_saving where 'monthly_saving.id'='coi_system.id' OR 'monthly_saving.id'='null'"` It turns out nothing is displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM coi_system INNER JOIN monthly_saving ON 'monthly_saving.id' = 'coi_system.id'
```

Comment: try this get a both table data

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *.coi_system, *.monthly_saving FROM coi_system INNER JOIN monthly_saving ON monthly_saving.id=coi_system.id"); 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $accountcode=$row['accountcode'];` but I got this error, mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result?

Comment: please try SELECT * FROM coi_system INNER JOIN monthly_saving ON 'monthly_saving.id' = 'coi_system.id'

Comment: make sure that id of monthly_saving is same as id of coi_system id

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT coi_system.*, monthly_saving.* FROM coi_system RIGHT JOIN monthly_saving ON monthly_saving.id=coi_system.id;
```

The right join would solve your problem if monthly saving is null.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *.coi_system, *.monthly_saving FROM coi_system INNER JOIN monthly_saving ON monthly_saving.id=coi_system.id"); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $accountcode=$row['accountcode'];` but I got this error, mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result?

Comment: @lessy edited the query, syntax wasnt correct. Try now?? It would be better if you try the query directly on php my admin instead of executing it on php. It would save time.

Comment: Ok theres no error anymore. But even if I use RIGHT JOIN it only display the 'monthly_saving' data while the rest wont display. I've tried INNER JOIN but it wont display any result at all and LEFT JOIN only display the 'coi_system' data. It wont display both the data together. Is it something wrong with mysql table? The id for the first table I set it as primary key and the second table id as index as I want it to refer from the first table.